Error when Connecting using SSMS
I'm attempting to connect to an Azure database using SSMS v20.2 and Microsoft Entra MFA for authentication. When I click connect, I get the below error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.38.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

I can connect via Azure Data Studio, but SSMS gives me trouble.
The solutions I'm finding online all have to do with projects in Visual Studio, which this is not - it's simply me trying to connect. I have tried a repair install, as well as completely uninstalling/reinstalling SSMS with no luck. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution?

I have also had this issue for a few weeks and have been troubleshooting this for two days now. I found the cause of the error for me. Do you by any chance have KingswaySoft Integration Toolkit Productivity Toolkit installed? This is what is breaking SSMS for me.
To figure out the cause, I formatted a laptop and installed a fresh Windows 11. Then I installed SSMS and checked it worked. Installed the following other software that I had installed when I first had the problem:

Visual Studio 2022
Microsoft Data Tools Integration Services (SSIS)
KingswaySoft Integration Toolkit Dynamics 365
KingswaySoft Integration Toolkit Productivity Toolkit

After each software was installed, I did two reboots and checked Windows Update for updates.
After installing KingswaySoft Integration Toolkit Productivity Toolkit SSMS broke for me with the same error. Uninstalling it and SSMS worked again.
Update: I have been in contact with KingswaySoft to bring the problem to their attention. They were quick to send me a prerelease version of the software. That did the trick for me. I can now have it installed without SSMS breaking. I am not allowed to share the file, but if anyone else has the same issue, they can contact KingswaySoft directly to get the prerelease version.

Great sleuthing. I hadn't even considered that it might be the KingswaySoft components, but I just uninstalled the productivity pack and voila! I was able to connect via SSMS. I've reached out to their support. I need the productivity pack installed, and I can work around the issue by using Azure Data Studio until I get the updated version.
